# Variable cannot be defined in AWT

Tags: java, awt

I am relatively new to coding in Java, and have just hit the subject of GUIs and user-generated events. I am trying to make a simple button-based narrative, however this error continues to pop up:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
>       careerNew cannot be resolved to a variable
>       responseText cannot be resolved to a variable

```
at SalutonFrame.actionPerformed(SalutonFrame.java:56)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my source code:

```
>import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

>public class SalutonFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    >public SalutonFrame() {
        super("Saluton Mondo!");
        setLookAndFeel();
        setSize(1000, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 10);
        setLayout(flow);
        >//set row 1
            >JButton careerNew = new JButton("Begin your programming career!");
            careerNew.addActionListener(this);
            JLabel responseLabel = new JLabel("YourResponse:", JLabel.RIGHT);
            JComboBox choiceResponse = new JComboBox();
            choiceResponse.addItem("Yes");
            choiceResponse.addItem("No, I'm an idiot");
            JTextField responseText = new JTextField(20);
            add(careerNew);
            add(choiceResponse);
            add(responseLabel);
            add(responseText);
        //set row 2
        JPanel badCareer = new JPanel();
            JButton startBad = new JButton("Start a life of misery");
            JLabel startBadLabel = new JLabel("Your Response, Not that it Matters though:", JLabel.RIGHT);
            JTextField startBadText = new JTextField (20);
            JComboBox startBadCombo = new JComboBox();
            startBadCombo.addItem("You dont have a choice");
            startBadCombo.addItem("You dont have a choice");
            startBadCombo.addItem("You dont have a choice");
            startBadCombo.addItem("You dont have a choice");
            startBadCombo.addItem("You dont have a choice");
            startBadCombo.addItem("You dont have a choice");
            startBadCombo.addItem("You dont have a choice");
            startBadCombo.addItem("You dont have a choice");
            startBadCombo.addItem("You dont have a choice");
            startBadCombo.addItem("You dont have a choice");
            startBadCombo.addItem("Dafuq u still looking?");
            badCareer.add(startBad);
            badCareer.add(startBadLabel);
            badCareer.add(startBadCombo);
            badCareer.add(startBadText);
        add(badCareer);




        setVisible(true);
    }
    // sets User-generated event from button careerNew
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            Object source = event.getSource();
            if (source.equals (careerNew)) {
            CareerGood career = new CareerGood();
            }
            else if (source == responseText) {
                JLabel fart = new JLabel("Idiot");

            }
        }



    private void setLookAndFeel() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                    "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        }
        catch (Exception exc) {


        }
    }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SalutonFrame frame = new SalutonFrame();        }
    }
```

Yes, I did ignore the message that Eclipse sent me about the running while there are errors. Please help me, as I am only just a beginner, and would like to have a career in Java programming. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `careerNew` as a local variable

```
JButton careerNew = new JButton("Begin your programming career!");
```

Its scope is limited to the constructor. You cannot reference it outside of the body of the constructor, as you are trying to do in the `actionPerformed()` method. You should instead make it an instance variable. You will be able to access it in any instance method.

The same applies to `responseText`.

Comment: wait hold on, excuse my "noobness", but how do i make it an instance variable (i read "Learn to Program in Java in 24 Hours" by Rogers Cadenhead and its a good book, its just kind of in a blur xD)

Comment: @user Take a look at the tutorials on Object and Classes [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/).

Comment: again, excuse my noobness, but does that mean that, in this case making careerNew into SalutonFrame.careerNew will solve the problem? Or did I read the tutorial all wrong? Again, excuse my questions, as i am just getting started with the language.

Comment: @user Instead of declaring the variable in the constructor, you declare it in the body of the class. This makes it an instance variable that can be accessed from any other instance member of the class. In [this example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html), `gear` is an instance variable of the class `Bicycle`. You need to do the same for `careerNew` in `SalutonFrame`.

Comment: I love you man xD thank you for your time and effort in answering my question, beceause i was being tackled and tossed by so many bugs and errors, and i was beginning to feel discouraged, but having people lk you to help really helps me kick myself back into the wonderful world of programming :)

Answer (score 0):

Java variables have scope, meaning that they can only be accessed in the set of brackets they're in. Right now, Java can't find the variables responseText and careerNew. To fix this, simply make them public.